# How to automatically unbox root array with moshi

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, moshi

The API I consume, thank to Retrofit, return a lot of json which the root level consist of a container with only a list inside of it, for example:

```
{
  "data": [
      ...
  ]
}
```

In this example the name is "data" but it may vary depending on the route.

Is there a way to automatically unbox it so only the list is returned ?

Comment: Is this the pattern you are looking for? https://medium.com/@naturalwarren/moshi-made-simple-jsonqualifier-b99559c826ad or maybe this https://medium.com/@hanru.yeh/how-to-parse-nested-json-from-retrofit-with-gson-11a64b21641f

Comment: @bjartek Thank you, first link did the job.

Comment: If you want to mark this question as answered. Feel free to accept the answer below